# Python how to filter the dataframe where substring in column A is found in string in column B?

Tags: python, dataframe, search, filter

In dataframe, I would like to filter it and keep the rows, if the string in label column is found within the string in the sentence column in the same row:

Input dataframe (some rows are empty):

| sentence | labels |
| --- | --- |
| A met B | A |
| C is dead | X |
|  | D |
| D went to London and Berlin | London and Berlin |
| E is sleeping |  |

Output dataframe:

| sentence | label |
| --- | --- |
| A met B | A |
| D went to London and Berlin | London and Berlin |

Comment: Should missing values be treated as strings or `NaN`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


s = """sentence labels
A met B A
C is dead   X
D
D went to London and Berlin London and Berlin
E is sleeping   """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\t")

print(df)
```

```
                      sentence             labels
0                      A met B                  A
1                    C is dead                  X
2                            D                NaN
3  D went to London and Berlin  London and Berlin
4                E is sleeping                NaN
```

Assuming the `NaN` values will be treated as empty strings...

```py
out = df.loc[
    # fill missing vals with empty strings to avoid TypeError
    df.fillna("")
    # check if labels in sentence iteratively 
    # while also making making sure labels are not empty
    .apply(
        lambda r: r["labels"] in r["sentence"] and bool(r["labels"]),
        axis="columns",
    )
]

print(out)
```

```
                      sentence             labels
0                      A met B                  A
3  D went to London and Berlin  London and Berlin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'sentence': ['A met B', 'C is dead','', 'Test Test'],
        'strcheck': ['A', 'JP','Clock', 'Test']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["strcheck"] not in row["sentence"]:        
        df = df.drop(index)                
print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering if there is a better way to do the same without iterrows, because it is very slow for big data? Cheers!

Comment: See Ian's answer below. It might be faster.